# Collection of resources for Web App Security?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security

Can anyone suggest some good resources, preferrably free, that I can read to thoroughly understand the basics of getting my web app secure?

It is being written with a Rails back-end, and regular HTML, CSS, jQuery front-end.

For instance, the proper security practices for handling users login. To storing info in the db, to anything else I might want to know.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.rorsecurity.info/

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html

Answer (score 2):

http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Ruby_on_Rails_Security_Guide_V2

Answer (score 0):

- [Restful Authentication](http://github.com/technoweenie/restful-authentication)
- [Oauth](http://oauth.rubyforge.org/)

These have some basic documentation with them, but these are used by a large number of Rails apps.